# Rstudio Rmarkdown Pandoc error 67

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

edit: Solved - Turning computer off and back on, and deleting R workspace.... Not sure why the error happened in the first place, any answers would still be appreciated.

I have received an error when trying to run:

```
rmarkdown::render("Home.Rmd")
```

I'm new to **R** and **Rmarkdown** and have no idea how to interpret the error - the error output I get is:

`Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m  RTS Home.utf8.md --to html --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output  Home.html --smart --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template "C:\Users\bfosh\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\rmarkdown\rmd\h\default.html" --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --include-before-body "C:\Users\bfosh\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqovuGu\rmarkdown-strfe8d3a5bf0.html" --variable navbar=1 --variable body_padding=51 --variable header_padding=56 --variable "theme:cerulean" --include-in-header "C:\Users\bfosh\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqovuGu\rmarkdown-strfe835066d89.html" --mathjax --variable "mathjax-url:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"' had status 67`

Is anyone able to tell me what the error message means/how to fix?

edit: Error occurs on every R markdown rendered regardless of script content.

Comment: If you do want help and an answer, please look up the helpcenter: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Solved by turning off and back on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by turning off and back on and deleting workspace. Reloading the .Rmd files into a new clean Rstudio (didn't work first 2 times, but third time did work...)

Not sure what created the error in the first place though.